# С#: вопрос по сокетам (таймаут сокета)

Tags: c#, сокет, сеть

**Добрый день!**

Подскажите мне пожалуйста, по такому вопросу. Разрабатываю клиент для сокета.

Есть 2 сообщения для отправки : "**0100**", "**0400**".

Мы можем принять только два сообщения: "**0110**", "**0410**" соответственно.
(0100->0110, 0400->0410)

**Алгоритм таков:**

1.отправляем **0100**.

2.ждем ответа (тайм аут).
если пришло сообщение **0110**, то все ок, прекращаем работу.

3.если таймаут сработал, то отправляем сообщение **0400** и ждем ответа.
если и тут срабатывает таймаут, то снова (и снова) отправляем **0400** до тех пор пока не придет **0410**. только потом начинаем сначала с пункта 1 до тех пора пока не придет ответ **0110**.

Есть код:

```
public string SendMessage(string message = "0100")
{
    //получаемое сообщение
    var bytesReceived = new Byte[40960]; //!!!!!!!! размер
    var buffer = new List<Byte>();
    socketClient.ReceiveTimeout = 5000;

    //ответ сервера
    string msg_input = "";

    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            // отправляем 0100
            byte[] msg_output = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Console.ReadLine());
            socketClient.Send(msg_output);

            //ждем в ответ 0110
            int bytes = socketClient.Receive(bytesReceived, 0, bytesReceived.Length, SocketFlags.None);
            buffer.AddRange(bytesReceived.Take(bytes));

            //читаем ответ с сервера
            msg_input = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesReceived, 0, bytes);
            break;
        }

        return msg_input;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

**Помогите пожалуйста дополнить код согласно алгоритму (не разберу как опеределить работу с таймаутом).**

Спасибо.

Comment: Возможно ответ гугла [Socket.ReceiveTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receivetimeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) на запрос `c# read socket timeout` это как раз то, что Вы ищете. / На шарпе не пишу, а в Си (C++) обычно IO таймауты реализуют используя вызовы select (или poll)

Comment: Эээ... А зачем вам такой огромный буфер?

Comment: И ещё, что за тип у переменной `socketClient`? Если это `Socket`, то зачем писать на таком низком уровне, а не взять высокоуровнывый `TcpClient`/`TcpListener`?